# RMI Permission Problem

Tags: java, permissions, rmi

I am struggling with a RMI permission problem. I have a server and a client program that both depend on a common project, which provides the package common.rmi with the interfaces.
In my server policy file I write

grant codeBase "file:path/to/bin/webui/common/rmi" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

When I start the client application I get an AccessControlException for a log file in the .metadata/.plugins eclipse file and one from (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader).
Does somebody know why?
I thought it is sufficient to grant a permission on the package with the interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codebase should point to a JAR file or to the head of a package-structured directory hierarchy of .class files. It looks like yours is pointing *into* the package structure.